# How do I map a palette from www.materialpalette.com to an Angular 2 theme?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Download link on otherwise excellent [www.materialpalette.com](http://www.materialpalette.com) doesn't support Angular 2. Downloading e.g. sass gives:

```
$primary-color-dark
$primary-color
$primary-color-light
$primary-color-text
$accent-color
$primary-text-color
$secondary-text-color
$divider-color
```

Looking for advise on exactly how to map these to Angular 2:

```
$app-primary: mat-palette(…);
$app-accent: mat-palette(…);
$app-warn: mat-palette(…);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!/ to generate a palette based on the colors provided by [materialpalette](http://www.materialpalette.com) so finally you get the file containing your colors e.g `/assets/your-palette.scss`:

```
$mat-your-palette: (
    50 : #e8eaf6,
    100 : #c5cbe9,
    200 : #9fa8da,
    300 : #7985cb,
    400 : #5c6bc0,
    500 : #3f51b5,
    600 : #394aae,
    700 : #3140a5,
    800 : #29379d,
    900 : #1b278d,
    A100 : #c6cbff,
    A200 : #939dff,
    A400 : #606eff,
    A700 : #4757ff,
    contrast: (
        50 : #000000,
        100 : #000000,
        200 : #000000,
        300 : #000000,
        400 : #ffffff,
        500 : #ffffff,
        600 : #ffffff,
        700 : #ffffff,
        800 : #ffffff,
        900 : #ffffff,
        A100 : #000000,
        A200 : #000000,
        A400 : #ffffff,
        A700 : #ffffff,
    )
);
```

Then based on the file above you have to create a theme e.g `/assets/theme.scss`:

```
@import '~@angular/material/_theming.scss';
@import './your-palette.scss';
@include mat-core();
$primary: mat-palette($mat-your-palette, 500);
$accent:  mat-palette($mat-your-palette, A100);
$warn:    mat-palette($mat-your-palette, A200);
$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

Then import your theme `@import '/assets/theme';` in `styles.scss` and you are done.
Also check the [docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) for more info on how to theme your app

**UPDATE:**
To figure out the colors for your custom theme could be a bit tricky. Currently to build `material2` theme you only need to provide 3 colors `$primary`, `$accent` and `$warn` As per [Theming Guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming):

- A `primary palette`: colors most widely used across all screens and
  components.
- An `accent palette`: colors used for the floating action
  button and interactive elements.
- A `warn palette`: colors used to
  convey error state.

Comment: Hi @Kuncevic just to confirm, the following items from materialpalette.com do not apply in A2 MD: ($primary-color-dark, $primary-color-light, $primary-color-text, $primary-text-color, $secondary-text-color and $divider-color), is that correct?  Also not clear which of these should be used for $app-warn.

Comment: You have just have to pick the base colors to generate the pallatte with http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!/. You always can adjust that until you are happy with result also you can just manually change the generated file. `warn palette`: colors used to convey error state (see the answer update). `materialpalette.com` is just a generic material colors generator so in case of `material2` custom theme you only need to provide 3 colors `$primary`, `$accent` and `$warn`

Comment: Still works great with Angular 7 and Angular Material 7