# Angular Material2 compatibility with Boostrap 3

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-material2

Is `Angular Material2` compatible with `Bootstrap 3`?

I want to use material2 date picker for my project which is using `Angular 4` and `Bootstrap 3`.

Comment: are you talking about https://github.com/angular/material2?

Comment: @Kuncevic, I was thinking about https://material.angular.io/.

Comment: Yes it is same thing, http://material.angular.io is just a doc site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about integration `bootstrap + angular material2` so the short answer is - it not quite a good practice.

Checkout some more details here [Can Bootstrap (4) be integrated along with Angular Material (2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497542/can-bootstrap-4-be-integrated-along-with-angular-material-2) same idea will apply to `bootstrap 3 + material2`

Comment: Two question then: First, does Angular Material 2 contains some simple styling or it contains just some interactive components? Second, what is the best date picker option with angular 2 and bootstrap 3?

Comment: you can override the default component styles and theme if you want to using your custom `scss` rules. Also you can create your own custom pallete if you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966889/how-do-i-map-a-palette-from-www-materialpalette-com-to-an-angular-2-theme Talking about the best bootstrap3 date picker I think you need to research on that and see which one is better suit your needs, there is a plenty options down there

Comment: @SirWojtek The answer you referenced was referring to **AngularJS Material** (1.x), not **Angular Material** (2.x)